# Copy to clip in Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Can I copy some text in Azure Function App?

Traditional way with

`Clipboard.SetText("Hello, clipboard");`

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The Azure Function gets executed on a machine in an **Azure datacenter** but not on your local pc. You probably should return the string you want in the Azure function and then you would be able to invoke the Azure function e. g. with a HttpTrigger in PowerShell, catch the result and set it to the Clipboard using the `Set-Clipboard` cmdlet.